# How do I use autologin cookie in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I would use this code to collect the user by a cookie from another application and when you enter this new application is still connected. It is possible? I tried this:

```
public class ALogin implements AutoLogin {
    public String[] login(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws AutoLoginException {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
           String acceso=(String)session.getAttribute("username");

        if (acceso == null || acceso.isEmpty())
            return null;
        System.out.println("VACIO");

        try {

            long companyId = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);
            User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId,
                    acceso);

               System.out.println("--------------------");

              /* Cookie cookie = null;
               Cookie[] cookies = null;

               cookies = request.getCookies();
               if( cookies != null ){
                  System.out.println("COOKIES");
                  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
                     cookie = cookies[i];
                     System.out.print("Nombre : " + cookie.getName() + ",  ");
                     System.out.print("Valor: " + cookie.getValue()+" <br/>");

          }
       }*/
               System.out.println("PRUEBA");

               Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();   

               if(cookies == null){
                   System.out.println("No tienes usuario para acceder aquí");
                }else{  
                    for (int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
                        if(cookies[i].getName().equals("username"))
                            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO: "+cookies[i].getValue());
                    }
                }

               System.out.println("--PRUEBA-");


            return new String[] { 
                    String.valueOf(user.getUserId()),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    String.valueOf(user.isPasswordEncrypted()) };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Ideas?????? 
Thank you!!! ;)

Comment: The both application have the same url path or not ? Which are urls of these applications ?

Comment: @Pracede They have different url. The cookie and I have kept from the first application. The second application is a hook of liferay, in which I pick up the cookie to keep an open session.

Comment: I now get into the second application the url: http://localhost:8080/ca/web/x/home/access=test

And I accessed directly without loguearme, because access = test user picks me.

I need you here Collect the session cookie and knows if the session is not open or no

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the cross domain one and is security reasons.  If the domains are subdomains you can share the cookies. In your case as the both applications does not have the same domain. It's not possible.